# Was the storm from The Perfect Storm (2000) a similar storm as Frankenstorm?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-perfect-storm

*[The Perfect Storm (2000)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0177971/)* was a movie about a some fishermen caught in a big storm:

> After debating whether to sail through the building storm or to wait it out, the crew decide to risk the storm. However, between the Andrea Gail and Gloucester is a confluence of two powerful weather fronts and a hurricane, which the Andrea Gail crew underestimate.
>   - [Excerpt from the plot section of Wikipedia article about *The Perfect Storm (film)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Perfect_Storm_%28film%29#Plot)

This is somewhat similar to Frankenstorm, which would result from the encounter of [Hurricane Sandy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurricane_Sandy) and a winter storm.

Is the perfect storm from the movie the same kind of storm as Frankenstorm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, its very similar in that you have a tropical depression absorbing a nor'easter.  Sandy has the added "benefit" of a full moon, which many are thinking will make it even more destructive than the 1991 storm that the movie is based on.